# Block code preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please I created a textarea preview just like the stackoverflow that displays the text you type instantly. And I believe I have gotten it right. Now I also what to enable the inline code (for example `this is an inline code`) which I have done and it works perfect. And here is my code:

```
$("#comment").keyup(function(){
if($(this).val() == ""){
   $('#preview').css('display','none');
}else{
   $('#preview').css('display','block');
}
// $("#preview").html($(this).val());
$("#preview").text($(this).val()); // If you want html code to be escaped
$("#preview").html($("#preview").html().replace(/`(.*?)`/g, "<span><code class='inline_code'>$1</code></span>"));
getting = document.getElementByTagName("code").html;
$("code").text(getting);
});
```

Now I want to use the same method for the block code (for example)

```
this is a block code
```

so I added this line of code below the `.replace` line This time replacing 4 empty spaces but only at the begining

```
$("#preview").html($("#preview").html().replace(/    (.*?)/g, "<span><code class='block_code'>$1</code></span>"));
```

but it just displays like the normal text without applying my css styling to it. so I also added another 4 empty spaces at the end

```
$("#preview").html($("#preview").html().replace(/    (.*?)    /g, "<span><code class='block_code'>$1</code></span>"));
```

And this time it works but I don't want the 4 empty spaces at the end. I only want it at the beginning so I don't have to give 4 spaces to end the code.

In summary, I just want my textarea and preview to work just like the stackoverflow. And if necessary here is my html:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="preview" class="preview"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten a solution to my question which I also gave as an answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859651/how-to-implement-a-numbered-list-in-a-textarea/38348866#38348866)

Here I did some project which looks much like the stackoverflow's. Though not 100% the same with stackoverflow but at least it has most features with the stackoverflow, You can check it out here (http://stack.stephensangkn.org). But I intentionally emitted the image uploading because it has to do with the server. I think it's pretty cool. You can also see a download link in the page to download the source code