# How to implement a numbered list in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I studied the [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) numbered list in the textarea and this is what I observered

### Observations

1. When the numbered list link is clicked, it inserts something like this `1. List Item` and when clicked again it inserts `2. List item`
2. Now if you have like `3` list items and you erase `1. List Item` and you click the link again or you breakdown two lines, the `2. List item` changes to `1. List Item` and `3` changes to `2` leaving you with `1. List Item` and `2. List Item` instead of `2. List Item` and `3. List Item`
3. Now if you have `3` list items and you breakdown two lines, type some text and click the link again, the list item start from `1. List Item` again
4. Finally, it automatically detects the previous list item number and increases by `1`. And it also detects the total amount of list item, if the previous one is `4` and the total amount of the list items are just two, it automatically changes them to `1. List Item` and `2. List Item`

This is a short [video](http://tutorials.stephensangkn.org/video/brag.php) showing my observations.

### What I want to achieve

I want to implement the same features StackOverflow uses.

1. When my link is clicked it inserts `1. List Item` in my textarea and auto-increases until two line break-downs are detected
2. If I eraze a list Item and click the link again or break down two line, the erazed link is been replaces automatically and respectively just like my No.2 observation
3. Just like my third observation, if I break-down two lines and type in some texts and click the link again, it starts from `1. List Item` and not from the last one I stopped.

### My work

This code below is what I use to add a text in a textarea

```
<a href="javascript:;" alt="text to add into textarea">click here for numbered list</a>
<textarea id="text_area"></textarea>
<script>
    $('a').click(function () {
       var text = $(this).attr('alt');
       ins2pos(text, 'text_area');
    });

    function ins2pos(str, id) {
       var TextArea = document.getElementById(id);
       var val = TextArea.value;
       var before = val.substring(0, TextArea.selectionStart);
       var after = val.substring(TextArea.selectionEnd, val.length);
       
       TextArea.value = before + str + after;
       setCursor(TextArea, before.length + str.length);
       
    }

    function setCursor(elem, pos) {
       if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
          elem.focus();
          elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
       } else if (elem.createTextRange) {
          var range = elem.createTextRange();
          range.collapse(true);
          range.moveEnd('character', pos);
          range.moveStart('character', pos);
          range.select();
       }
    }
</script>
```

### My Question

Please how do I achieve these. I think the best way to do it is through `jQuery` and `JavaScript`. But if there are any alternatives I would appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I did some project which looks much like the stackoverflow's. Though not 100% the same with stackoverflow but at least it has most features with the stackoverflow, You can check it out here (http://stack.stephensangkn.org). But I intentionally emitted the image uploading because it has to do with the server. I think it's pretty cool. You can also see a download link in the page to download the source code

Answer (score 1):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. You can easily just create a `contentEditable` div and alter it's contents for an ordered list every time the click is fired:

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;">click here for numbered list</a>
  <div id="text_area" contentEditable="true">
    <ol></ol>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('a').click(function () {
    $('ol').append("<li class='list-item'></li>");
    $('.list-item').each(function(i){
      $(this).text('List Item');
    })
});
```

**CSS**

Make sure that the div looks like a text area:

```
#text_area{
  height:auto;
  width:400px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid silver;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

You can see that the default HTML list properties along with it being contentEditable makes it easy to delete list nodes and add them while keeping the numbering intact.

https://jsfiddle.net/r9ev1oe9/1/

You can handle situations of adding more than one list by creating 2 buttons. One that creates a new list, and one that adds list items to that list.

Comment: its pretty cool, but its not exactly what I need. when I erase a list item, the link doesn't function again. And when I breakdown and add some texts and click the link again, it just starts from where the previous list stopped

Comment: That's where splitting the two separate buttons come into play. When you delete the only list item, it deletes the <ol> as well.

Comment: Take a look at this. It's not complete, but it's something for you to work with: https://jsfiddle.net/r9ev1oe9/2/